# Excel spread sheet multiple VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, vba

On an Excel spreadsheet I have 2 sheets. One sheet one has 4 different columns which contains 4 different user types. Each cell on those columns (A1 - 4 users, A2 - 3 users, B1 - 6 users, etc.) has multiple users (firstname, lastname) listed.

On spreadsheet 2 all users (firstname, lastname) are listed in A column and "User IDs" are listed in B column.

What I'm trying to accomplish by using `VLOOKUP` is replacing all the usernames in spreadsheet 1 with User IDs from spreadsheet 2.

Is this possible?? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You will need to do the vlookup in a different cell. A vlookup can not refer to itself.

Comment: Can you provide some example data please?

Answer (score 0):

Example would be something like

one cell would hold multiple values and the lookup table would hold these 2 values in separate cells.  So ideally the desired result would be 
in the same cell the problem is that after the lookup finds one value it doesnt keep looking up the rest of the data in the cells.

[Image of example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL9am.png)